# Multiple polymorphic fields in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, polymorphism

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :person_attributes
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phone_numbers, :as => :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
    has_one :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :phoneable, :polymorphic => true  
end

<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.fields_for :person do |person_form| %>
        <%= person_form.fields_for :phone_numbers do |phone_number_form| %>
            <%= phone_number_form.text_field :number %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works.  It does what I expect, but I want more than one phone number in my form.  How can I accomplish that?

```
user[person_attributes][phone_numbers_attributes][0][number]
```

Why does fields_for add [0] ?

If I want multiple phone numbers, would the second look like this?

```
user[person_attributes][phone_numbers_attributes][1][number]
```

If so, how?

If I can get multiple phone numbers in the database, my next question will be how to include other phone number attributes along with each number?  e.g.: description

```
user[person_attributes][phone_numbers_attributes][0][number]
user[person_attributes][phone_numbers_attributes][0][description]
```

Answer (score 0):

fields_for adds "[0]" because its a many relationship and it needs to make an array, with an index for each relation member [0], [1] ...

So yes, the second would have [1], rails adds that by itself via the helpers.

To include other phone number attributes:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.fields_for :person do |person_form| %>
        <%= person_form.fields_for :phone_numbers do |phone_number_form| %>
            <%= phone_number_form.text_field :number %>
            <%= phone_number_form.text_field :description %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```